# what is the issue with my code for Rearrange an array such that arr[i] = i?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to Rearrange an array such that each element located in its index. Or in result of program if `element` exist in that array: `Output_array[element] = element` located in its location otherwise  `Output_array[element] = -1`.

For example if input array be :

```
a= [-1,-1,6,3,5,9,1,0,8,2]
```

then output is:

```
output_array= [0,1,2,3,-1,5,-1,-1,8,9]
```

as you see, if we ignore `-1` in this array: then `output_array` is sorted.

this is a Python 3 code. it is printing some elements correctly, but not all

```
def solve(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range (n):
        if i in a:
            a[i] = i
        else:
            a[i] = -1
    print(a)

a= [-1,-1,6,3,5,9,1,0,8,2]
solve(a)
```

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what he's trying to accomplish

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I think he wants to sort it that `arr[i] = i`. So like, `arr[0] = 0` @FranciscoCouzo

Answer (score 1):

**Problems**:

The problem is element at an index is replaced with -1 if it's not present.

When the code tries to check 5, 5 is already replaced by -1 in the previous step (`a[4] = -1` (since 4 is not in the list), which is replacing 5). Similarly for the rest of the anomaly cases.

To better understand what's happening, add some `print`s:

```
def solve(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        if i in a:
            a[i] = i
            print(a)
            print(i)
        else:
            a[i] = -1
    print(a)
```

**Solution**:

One solution would be to use a list comprehension which does this in one line and is pretty faster:

```
[i if i in a else -1 for i in range(len(a))]
```

In function:

```
def solve(a):
    return [i if i in a else -1 for i in range(len(a))]
```

And call it as:

```
>>> solve([-1,-1,6,3,5,9,1,0,8,2])
[0, 1, 2, 3, -1, 5, 6, -1, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Just to add, fixing it would just require another list to be changed instead of `a`.

Comment: your solution gives the same result as mine

Comment: Does not look same to me: `[0,1,2,3,-1,5,-1,-1,8,9]` vs `[0, 1, 2, 3, -1, 5, 6, -1, 8, 9]`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your trying to achieve an array with elements arranged into their respective index value.

The thing happening here is since the list is a ***mutable data type*** your data is being overwritten with every iteration and due to this not all values are being arranged.

for example your list after loop running from `i=0 to i=3` becomes

```
[0,1,2,3,5,9,1,0,8,2]
```

You see you have lost some of your data like 6 due to changes in list,try using different list to store changes!!

Answer (score 0):

The point is that when i reaches 6, 6 is no more in a, because a[2] was set to -1 when i was 2 ! You should first make a copy of a into b, and your condition should be `if i in b` instead of `if i in a`

Answer (score 0):

I used another list, you could use another array, not matter.

```py
def solve(a):
    n = len(a)
    c=[]
    for i in range (n):
        if i in a:
          c.append(i)
        else:
          c.append(-1)
    print(a)
    print(c)
a= [-1,-1,6,3,5,9,1,0,8,2]
solve(a)
```

And output :

> [-1, -1, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 0, 8, 2]
>
> [0, 1, 2, 3, -1, 5, 6, -1, 8, 9]

**What was issue with your code?**
In this part of your code: you changed element in forward index `i` and be changing them, you lost them and not able to find in the remaining index of `for` loop.

```py
if i in a:
    a[i] = i
else:
    a[i] = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def solve(a):
    return [i if i in a else -1 for i in range(len(a))]

# Test
a = [3, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4]
print(solve(a))
```

**Result**:

```
[0, -1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```